# Which LogFactory to use?

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

I want to `log.debug` from `src/groovy`. The 2.1.1 Grails user guide says to it like this:

```
package org.other
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class MyClass {
    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
    …
}
```

But `import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory` works (in dev environment) as well. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Groovy standard @Log annotation. That will inject a log instance into your class. Read more here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Logging